# How to persist level db data on local file system or any other database

Tags: node.js, in-memory-database, leveldb

I am working nodejs application which uses LevelDb. LevelDB is a fast key-value storage library written at Google that provides an ordered mapping from string keys to string values.

Whenever I restart the application server, levelDB data removed from memory. I want to persist LevelDB data on local file system or any other database so that for every startup service of server will get that data.

Comment: What module you use? this one use db file https://www.npmjs.com/package/level

Comment: @yeya what can I do so that my db file will not removed the data if kinesalite also creates db file ?

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use `--path <path>` in cli mode,

Or `{path: './mydb'}` programmatically

It's all [here](https://github.com/mhart/kinesalite#example)